# How to restrict access to api

Tags: api

Good.
Im developing mobile application. In fact, it's client for web service. How can I restrict access to my web service only from this application?

As an alternative. Using RSA encoding with an extra secret key. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Are you developing the client or the server side of the webservice? If you are developing both, you could e.g. send credentials in your request body, hardcoding it in your application (if you connect to your WS over a secured protocol). Or you use basic authentication or whatever else you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can achieve Web service authentication most basic is via username/password verification over SSL. While many technologies you are implementing your clients and servers offer various kind of authentication and authorization mechanisms.
For ex if you are writing code in .net https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Service_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Few more examples with Java:
http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200603/WSSecurity.html

Plain SOAP authentication standard:
http://www.whitemesa.com/soapauth.html

Google: [This](https://www.google.dk/search?q=web%20service%20security%20authentication%20authorization)